# where to find the source in openjdk

Tags: java

Hi
   I installed openjdk1.6 in my machine using yum.

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

it is installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/

But I could not find the java source of the classes.

What I'm trying to do is just edit some original java code, recompile and play with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually download it using `mercurial` , first of all get [`Mercurial Forest Extension`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ForestExtension) and then clone the whole tree

```
hg fclone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6
```

Building it is a bit tricky, [`here`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html) is the build howto for JDK7, should be applicable for JDK6 too.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package from yum, you're installing a binary. It doesn't necessarily download the source. You'll probably have to download the source from the website (or a repository) directly.

http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/